# getting similar predictions on data while predicting using tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, data-science

I am a beginner in machine learning and I am working on a simple project to predict the electricity consumption of a household using data available [here](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/individual+household+electric+power+consumption#).

The data consists of the global minute averaged active power of every minute for 4 years. The head of the data looked something like this.

```
 Date      Time  Global_active_power  Global_reactive_power  Voltage  \
0  16/12/2006  17:24:00                4.216                  0.418   234.84   
1  16/12/2006  17:25:00                5.360                  0.436   233.63   
2  16/12/2006  17:26:00                5.374                  0.498   233.29   
3  16/12/2006  17:27:00                5.388                  0.502   233.74   
4  16/12/2006  17:28:00                3.666                  0.528   235.68   

   Global_intensity  Sub_metering_1  Sub_metering_2  Sub_metering_3  
0              18.4             0.0             1.0            17.0  
1              23.0             0.0             1.0            16.0  
2              23.0             0.0             2.0            17.0  
3              23.0             0.0             1.0            17.0  
4              15.8             0.0             1.0            17.0
```

Then I combined the date and time column to create a datetime object and then created a new timestamp column and saved the 'ts' and 'Global_active_power' in a different csv file using the following code.

```
df['Timestamp']=pd.to_datetime(df['Date']+ ' '+df['Time'])
df=df[['Global_active_power','ts']]
df['ts'] = df.Timestamp.values.astype(np.int64)
df.to_csv('final.csv')
```

The head of final.csv looked something like this

```
     Global_active_power           ts
0                4.216  1166289840000000000
1                5.360  1166289900000000000
2                5.374  1166289960000000000
3                5.388  1166290020000000000
4                3.666  1166290080000000000
```

Then I created a multilayer perceptron model using tensorflow to predict the global_active_power on the basis of the timestamp (using timestamp ts as feature and global_active_power as label) using the following code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

data=pd.read_csv('final.csv',dtype={'Global_active_power': 'float'})
data.fillna(0,inplace=True)
data=data.values
n = data.shape[0]
p = data.shape[1]
train_start = 0
train_end = int(np.floor(0.95*n))
test_start = train_end
test_end = n
data_train = data[np.arange(train_start, train_end), :]
data_test = data[np.arange(test_start, test_end), :]
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(data_train)
data_train=scaler.transform(data_train)
data_test=scaler.transform(data_test)

X_train=data_train[:,1]
X_train=X_train.reshape(-1,1)
X_test=data_test[:,1]
X_test=X_test.reshape(-1,1)
Y_train=data_train[:,0]
Y_test=data_test[:,0]

X = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,1])
Y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None])

sigma = 1
weight_initializer = tf.variance_scaling_initializer(mode="fan_avg", distribution="uniform", scale=sigma)
bias_initializer = tf.zeros_initializer()

# Model architecture parameters
n_features = 1
n_neurons_1 = 1024
n_neurons_2 = 512
n_neurons_3 = 256
n_neurons_4 = 128
n_target = 1
# Layer 1: Variables for hidden weights and biases
W_hidden_1 = tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_features, n_neurons_1]))
bias_hidden_1 = tf.Variable(bias_initializer([n_neurons_1]))
# Layer 2: Variables for hidden weights and biases
W_hidden_2 = tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_neurons_1, n_neurons_2]))
bias_hidden_2 = tf.Variable(bias_initializer([n_neurons_2]))
# Layer 3: Variables for hidden weights and biases
W_hidden_3 = tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_neurons_2, n_neurons_3]))
bias_hidden_3 = tf.Variable(bias_initializer([n_neurons_3]))
# Layer 4: Variables for hidden weights and biases
W_hidden_4 = tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_neurons_3, n_neurons_4]))
bias_hidden_4 = tf.Variable(bias_initializer([n_neurons_4]))

# Output layer: Variables for output weights and biases
W_out = tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_neurons_4, n_target]))
bias_out = tf.Variable(bias_initializer([n_target]))

# Hidden layer
hidden_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W_hidden_1), bias_hidden_1))
hidden_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_1, W_hidden_2), bias_hidden_2))
hidden_3 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_2, W_hidden_3), bias_hidden_3))
hidden_4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_3, W_hidden_4), bias_hidden_4))

# Output layer (must be transposed)
out = tf.transpose(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_4, W_out), bias_out))

# Cost function
mse = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(out, Y))

# Optimizer
opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(mse)

sess = tf.Session()


epochs=1
batch_size=256


sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

for epoch in range(epochs):
    shuffle_indices = np.random.permutation(np.arange(len(Y_train)))
    X_train = X_train[shuffle_indices]
    Y_train = Y_train[shuffle_indices]
    epoch_loss=0
    for i in range(0, len(Y_train)//batch_size):
        start=i*batch_size
        batch_x=X_train[start:start+batch_size]
        batch_y=Y_train[start:start+batch_size]
        _,c=sess.run([opt,mse],feed_dict={X:batch_x,Y:batch_y})
        epoch_loss+=c
    print('Epoch',epoch,'completed out of',epochs,'loss:',epoch_loss)

mse_final=sess.run(mse, feed_dict={X: X_test, Y: Y_test})
print('Final Error',mse_final)
```

I am running only one epoch because it was taking too long to run one epoch and the decrease in epoch loss after every epoch was very insignificant.

After running the following code I got this output

```
Epoch 0 completed out of 1 loss: 61.614460044074804
Final Error 0.008720885
```

But when I saw the predicted output and compared it to the Y_test the predicted output had almost same value for every element.

```
pred = sess.run(out, feed_dict={X: X_test})
```

Comment: What are you asking? As you stated, the output values are almost equal to Y_test, well that is what the final Error is telling you.

Comment: @ITiger The predicted values are almost same for all elements and the epoch loss is also decreasing very insignificantly after every epoch.

Comment: Well, you train your network for just one Epoch. Thats why there is just little training progress. The randomly initialized weights are only updated during one Epoch, so one should not expect great accuracy. Just train it for a few more epochs, Like 500 and Report again if you can see some progress

Comment: @ITiger Each epoch takes around 7-8 minutes on my system how will I be able to run 500? And there is nothing wrong with my code right?

Comment: You can accelerate the training time by reducing the number of hidden layers. This also reduces the degree of freedom in your model. IMHO you are going to overfit your data in the long run, as you only train on one variable. Try it with one hidden layer first. Another option would be to use Tensorflow with GPU support, if you do not do so already.